# Cant update MS Access Database from vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

I can add, delete, and search data on my MS access through vb.net application but cant update. It runs and finishes the update query but isn't updating the database, don't get any errors either. I'm new to VB.net and sql and have been following a guide to get what I have so far.

Coding I used for adding new record (Works fine for me):

```
Private Sub Savebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Addbtn.Click
        Dim Insertquery As String = "Insert into Risk_Register(ID, Risk_Name, Risk_Description, Owner, Control, Probability, Impact, Risk_Level) values (@ID, @Risk_Name, @Risk_Description, @Owner, @Control, @Probability, @Impact, @Risk_Level)"
        Runquery(Insertquery)
        MsgBox("The record has been added successfully to the database.", 0, "Information")
    End If
End Sub
```

For Update (Not updating)

```
Private Sub Updatebtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Updatebtn.Click
    Dim Updatequery As String = "Update Risk_Register Set Risk_Name=@Risk_Name, Risk_Description=@Risk_Description, Owner=@Owner, Control=@Control, Probability=@Probability, Impact=@Impact, Risk_Level=@Risk_Level Where ID=@ID"
    Runquery(Updatequery)
    MsgBox("The record has been updated successfully in the database.", 0, "Information")
End Sub
```

RunQuery Coding

```
Public Sub Runquery(ByVal query As String)

    con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\ahmed\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjectDatabase2003.mdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtRiskid.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Name", txtRiskname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Description", txtRiskdescription.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Owner", txtOwner.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Control", txtControl.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Probability", txtProbability.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Impact", txtImpact.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Risk_Level", txtRisklevel.Text)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Maybe the contents of txtRiskid.Text doesn't match any rows in the database?

Comment: When searching or deleting records I use txtRiskid.Text to complete those functions and it works when I do that but just not when I try to update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with the OleDb provider, Access does not recognize parameters by name.  You must supply the parameter values in the order Access expects them.

In your `UPDATE`, Access expects the `@ID` value last.  But your `RunQuery` procedure supplies it as the first parameter value.

You can modify the procedure to supply `@ID` first for an `INSERT` and last for an `UPDATE`.  Or you can use `RunQuery` for `INSERT` and create a separate version for `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think the solution was that simple, I was trying to fix it for hours.